# CMake include native library build as external project in Android library

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-library

I want to create a simple android library that only contains a shared native library, which is supposed to get loaded via `System.loadLibrary` at a later step.

However I'm not able to add my external project to the *.aar. For some reasons gradle doesn't even bother to build it. However, when I use `cmake` directly on the CMakeList, the external project and its resulting library is at least built correctly, but also not included in the cmake export/result.

My snippet looks like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  spatialite
  URL https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-5.0.1.tar.gz
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/spatialite-prefix/src/spatialite/configure
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/spatialite-prefix/src/spatialite/src/.libs/mod_spatialite.so
)

add_library(mod_spatialite SHARED IMPORTED)
add_dependencies(mod_spatialite spatialite)

set_target_properties(mod_spatialite PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/spatialite-prefix/src/spatialite/src/.libs/mod_spatialite.so")
```

The external project is built using make, not CMake.

The library of concern (mod_spatialite.so) is existing under the correct path above.

CMake doesnt give me any hints like warnings/information etc.

For testing reasons e.g. adding `add_library(x SHARED dummy.c)` will result in a new library called "libx.so" which is later on included in the *.aar file, which I'm trying to do with my external project too.